# A Confused Riddle Subject

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> I thought that I was a kind of cake...
>
> Or no, maybe installing without me would be an ache!
>
> Oh, I've got it now: I surely convey stuff.
>
> I give up... I'm some pasta. Enough!
>
> Can you solve my identity crisis?

Comment: You say it's your first word riddle, but you don't have the word tag.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @Austin Weaver are any of the answers below correct, or on the right track?

Comment: Schepler's answer is right, I'm just waiting to accept. This riddle turned out to be *way* broader (12 answers... jeez) than expected

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My guess is:

> Butterfly.

Kind of cake:

> A butterfly cake is one in which you bake a regular circular cake, then cut it into half and turn the two halves around next to each other before frosting.  (Or maybe use special pans to bake two half-circular cakes so you get proper crusts on the "wing edges", I don't remember exactly.)

Installing without me would be an ache:

> Butterfly hinges for installing a door.

Convey stuff:

> Butterfly valves convey fluid.

Type of pasta:

> *Farfalle* is Italian for butterflies.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about the final answer; however:

I thought that I was a kind of cake...

> macaroon

Or no, maybe installing without me would be an ache!

> macro

Oh, I've got it now: I surely convey stuff.

> macron

I give up... I'm some pasta. Enough!

> macaroni

Can you solve my identity crisis?

> Marco? A Mac?

Comment: Nope: Macaroons are cookies, not cakes.

Comment: @AustinWeaver noun: cookie;     1.    North American    a small sweet cake, typically round, flat, and crisp.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that. Either way, not the intended answer.

Comment: 2. informal;
a person of a specified kind.

Answer (score 5):

I thought that I was a kind of cake...

> Cannoli are yummy Italian pastries.

Or no, maybe installing without me would be an ache!

> Replacing a tooth without a root **Canal**? Ouch!

Oh, I've got it now: I surely convey stuff.

> Canals are used the world over for transportation of people, goods, and cannoli.

I give up... I'm some pasta. Enough!

> Cannelloni are a cylindrical type of pasta generally served baked

Which makes the final answer:

> "Canal," I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> a pen?

Because:

A cake:

> Pen is like pan, so pancake.

Installing without me... ache.:

> (shaky reason) a Pen like a cage to keep animals in. If you had to do some work in there (installation) and they ran out, that would be a real ache.

Convey stuff:

> Like writing? or could be a pan to transfer stuff.

some Pasta:

> penne

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite right.

Comment: (-----____-----)

Comment: @AustinWeaver you wrote "word riddle" that's why I thought this... oh well.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> a cup?

I thought that I was a kind of cake...

> A cupcake!

Or no, maybe installing without me would be an ache!

> A cup of (J)ava, that is.

Oh, I've got it now: I surely convey stuff.

> Like liquids, from one place to another.

I give up... I'm some pasta. Enough!

> Cup Noodles are a brand of pasta.

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> Urinal?

I thought that I was a kind of cake...

> Urinal cake

Or no, maybe installing without me would be an ache!

> I always have to "go" during a large install

Oh, I've got it now: I surely convey stuff.

> Takes the yellow stuff away. :)

I give up... I'm some pasta. Enough!

> Letssee...something having to do with "Penne," or "Noodle," --- use your imagination!

Comment: Got a +1 from me for the chuckle.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a layer?
>  Explanation
>  A layer cake, a layer (of bricks etc) makes installation a pain, layer is the term for the layer of information in computers, a layered pasta is a thing like lasagna.

Comment: Not this either, nice try though

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> Money

A cake

> Pound cake (pound being UK currency)

Installation

> Money helps to buy software for easy installation, without which it would be an ache to install the pirated version.

Conveyance

> Money helps to transport items or people from one place to other place.

Pasta

> Penne pasta (penne often pronounced "penny" like the smallest current form of UK currency)

Answer (score 2):

Any chance you're having trouble identifying as a:

> Funnel?

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning a bit more?

Comment: @puzzledPig, eh, I meant to. Now I've forgotten.

Comment: @puzzledPig I can see the relation. Funnel cake, a funnel makes oil changes much easier, the funnel conveys liquids, and...pasta...idk, i guess the bottom of the funnel looks a tiny bit like a pasta noodle.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're some sort of

> package manager

I just don't know which one.

Possibilities:

> [npm](https://npmjs.org) has a lot of different explanations of their acronym on their site (https://github.com/npm/npm-expansions). This could point to an identity crisis. Also, it means that the acronym conveys a lot of different meanings. There are three acronyms about pasta, one about macaroni, and surely some about cake too.

Or

> I believe there's a package manager called `make`, which sounds like cake, is a verb (so conveys meaning) and is somewhat close to macaroni in terms of spelling

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Circle  or Cylinder

"I thought that I was a kind of cake"

> Cake is usually depicted as a circle or cylinder. 
>  Circle is associated with pi(3.141) , pie being associated with cake.

"maybe installing without me would be an ache"

> For software installations a circular symbol which shows the progress of the installation would relate to circle being the answer. (Mostly UI dependent).
>  Installation of pipes(cylinder) is necessary for construction of houses.

"Oh, I've got it now: I surely convey stuff."

> Zero is used in mathematics to convey something(By conveying nothing).
>  Pipes convey water(or any other stuff).

"I give up... I'm some pasta. Enough!"

> Penne pasta looks like cylinder which is associated with circle. (Looks like a circle from top).